# Mongo DB didn't connect with my node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new in node and mongo.
I'm trying to connect mongo db with my node server but this error appears.
Error:getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND locahost
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

server.js

```
`const express = require('express');
require('colors');
const products = require('./data/products');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

//dotenv config
dotenv.config();
const { connectDb } = require('./config/config')
connectDb();
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Welcome to Node server</h1>')
})

app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
    res.json(products);
})

app.get('/products/:id', (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find(p => p.id === req.params.id);
    res.json(product);
})

const PORT = 8080;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${process.env.PORT}`.inverse.green)
})`
```

config.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('colors');
const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        })
        console.log(`MongoDB connected ${conn.connection.host}`.yellow)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error:${error.message}`.inverse.red);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

module.exports = { connectDb }
```

.env

```
PORT = 8080
NODE_ENV = development
MONGO_URI = mongodb://locahost:27017/local
```

Comment: You have mistype-d the `localhost`. It must be **mongodb://localhost:27017/local**

Comment: @ErfanMotallebi Thanks you